# How to display all selected users on click in vue

Tags: arrays, vue.js, onclick, event-handling, alert

I`m trying to make a table in vue. Where the user can select different workers and have their information displayed on the screen. I am very new to vue so don't really know how to do this. What I currently have can be seen below any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for my button :

```
    DataTable 
:style="{opacity: working ? 0.3 : 1}"
responsiveLayout="scroll"
dataKey="id"
filterDisplay="menu"
showGridlines
editMode="row"
v-model:selection="selectedWorkers" 
removableSort
v-model:filters="filters"
:value="workers"
:globalFilterFields="filterFields"
:paginator="true"
:rows="8">

<template #header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5">
        <input class="form-control" v-model="filters.global.value" placeholder="Keyword Search" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <button 
          type="button" 
          class="btn"
          :class="filters.global.value ? 'btn-secondary' : 'btn-outline-secondary'"
          :disabled="!filters.global.value" 
           @click="clearFilter">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5v-2zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2h-11z"/>
          </svg>
          <i class="bi bi-funnel"></i> 
          Clear
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <button 
          type="button" 
          class="btn"
          severity="info"
          :disabled="!selectedWorkers || !selectedWorkers.length"
           @click="addToList(data)">
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
            <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/>
          </svg>
          Add to List
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
        
</template>

<Column selectionMode="multiple" headerStyle="width: 3rem"></Column>
```

Js Code :

```
    data() {
    return {
      selectedWorkers: null,
    };
  },

    methods: {

    addToList() {
      
      alert(this.selectedWorkers)
      
    },
```

The current code returns [object Object] for each selected worker. Therefore that means that the selection part is working just cant get the data to display.

Current table to give you and idea

[image]

Message currently displayed

[image]

Comment: please provide more of a [mcve]. what is `data`?

Comment: Sorry data isn't anything I've just been trying different tutorials online and accidentally left it in. I have a data table with a set of workers who can be selected. Once the users are selected I want to click a button and for now have their data displayed on the screen. The selected users are saved in the selectedWorkers: null section.

Comment: please include code with data-table, for a better display of object try `JSON.stringify(this.selectedWorkers)`

Comment: Ok, I`ve added the data table code I think that's what you wanted. And oh yeah that works. It shows the data but not in the write format

Comment: is this all about the right format-what is the format you want? what is the person/data format (what are the keys of the object)?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for now I would like to display the id and the name of each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the right format you probably want to map over `selectedWorkers` to select the keys you want (id and name), using string template syntax. Then use `join` to combine the result

```
alert(this.selectedWorkers.map(worker=>`${worker.id}-${worker.name}`).join())
```

Example of assumed format:

```js
const selectedWorkers = [{
  id: 'AA',
  name: 'Lou Poole'
},{
  id: 'BB',
  name: 'Jonathan Fuller'
}]

alert(selectedWorkers.map(worker => `${worker.id}-${worker.name}`).join())
```